# xargs not behaving as expected with input delimited by newlines

Tags: shell-script, xargs

I want to run the same command on multiple lines of input. Gnu xargs seemed an obvious fit however it is not behaving as I would expect.

When I feed it multi-line input with `-d '\n'` the input lines are joined together and the command run once:

```
root@liv-wa01-si-lamp:/usr/local/bin/test# ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  2 14:28 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  2 14:28 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  2 14:28 c
root@liv-wa01-si-lamp:/usr/local/bin/test# ls -l | xargs -d '\n' echo "I found "
I found  total 0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  2 14:28 a -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  2 14:28 b -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  2 14:28 c
```

(my input is not a directory listing - its the output of an awk script, but behaves the same as the above).

Comment: `xargs` collects multiple arguments and runs the command once with all those arguments, or at least with as many arguments as can be passed to one exec. So it's behaving exactly as you ask.

Comment: IOW, it's `echo` here that joins its argument with spaces. Use `xargs -n1` to run one `echo` per line of input or `xargs -rd '\n' printf 'I found %s\n'` for a command that prints its arguments one per line.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas : thank you, that's what I was missing. If you post this as an aswer I'll mark it as accepted.